# Inequality for complicated expression

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

Suppose that $b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b=\dfrac{r\ln 2}{p},$ where $r=\left\lfloor\dfrac{k^2}{2}\right\rfloor$ and $p=\dfrac{2\binom{r/2}{k}}{\binom{r}{k}}$, where $k$ is an integer.

I was wondering is it possible to show that for sufficiently large $k$ we have $b\leq k^22^k$.

Comment: So, do you mean $b = \lceil (r/p)\ln 2 \rceil$?

Comment: @RiverLi, yes exactly!

Comment: @RiverLi, can you give an answer to this post?

Comment: Did you look at Rondoudou's answer?

Comment: @RiverLi, yes but as he said his proof does not work for odd $r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need Stirling's approximation :

$$ n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n $$

Since $r \sim k^2/2$, $k \sim \sqrt{2 r}$, a computation shows that :

$$ \binom{r}{k} = \frac{r!}{k! (r-k)!} \sim e^{-1} \frac{r^{k}}{k!} $$

Likewise,

$$ \binom{r/2}{k} \sim e^{-2} \frac{r^k}{k! 2^k} $$

Therefore, $p \sim 2 e^{-1} 2^{-k}$. This implies :

$$ b \sim \frac{1}{2} e \ln(2) 2^k r \sim \frac{e \ln(2)}{4} k^2 2^k $$

Now you may compute numerically $\frac{e \ln(2)}{4} \simeq 0.47$. This means that, asymptotically, the inequality you ask for is indeed true. [Sorry, I edited]

NB : I think this is a typo, but $b \notin \mathbb{Z}$ in your setting. $r$ is always rational as well as $p$, while $\ln(2)$ is not, so $b$ is not even rational. If you take the closest integer, the above computation remains correct.

EDIT : I compute generally that, when $k \sim c \sqrt{n}$ for some $c > 0$, then

$$ \binom{n}{k} \sim e^{-c^2/2} \frac{n^k}{k!} $$

and this implies the results above.

Indeed :

$$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!} \sim \frac{1}{k!} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi n}{2 \pi (n-k)} } \exp \left( n \ln(n) - k - (n-k) \ln(n-k) \right) \\
\sim \frac{n^k}{k!} \exp \left( -(n-k) \ln\left( 1-\frac{k}{n}\right) - k \right) \\
\sim \frac{n^k}{k!} \exp \left( \frac{k(n-k)}{n} + \frac{k^2 (n-k)}{2n^2} + o(1) - k \right) \\
\sim \frac{n^k}{k!} \exp \left( -\frac{k^2}{2n} \right) \\
\sim \frac{n^k}{k!} \exp \left( - c^2/2 \right) $$

EDIT 2 : As pointed out by @ZFR , $r$ is always even (either $k^2 \equiv 0 ~ [4]$, either $k^2 \equiv 1 ~ [4]$) so one has indeed the right to consider $\binom{r/2}{k}$.

Comment: Excuse me but can you clarify your steps with $\sim$ sign? They do not look rigorous to me.

Comment: Well, they are obtained by developping using Stirling's formula. I will edit.

Comment: Thank you! How are you gonna use Stirling's formula if $r/2$ is not integer? You are right that $b\notin \mathbb{Z}$ but I meant to take integer which is slightly larger than $\frac{r\ln 2}{p}$.

Comment: Indeed, $r/2$ is not even an integer... I assumed it was some close integer. For $b$, even if you take the closest integer, my asymptotic remains true. (PS : I edited.)

Comment: Sorry but I guess we misunderstood each other. Stirling's formula is true for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ but $r/2$ may not be an integer, then you obtained that asymptotics for $\binom{r/2}{k}$?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. There are two possibilities : Stirling's formula is actually true for n real if you extend $n!$ by the Gamma function (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Stirling's_formula) ) ; on the other hand, what I said was untrue : if you replace $r/2$ by the floor or ceil integer, the asymptotic actually changes (and quite a lot). Nonetheless, $r/2$ is an integer when $k$ is even.

Comment: Btw, note that $\binom{r/2}{k}$ does not have a clear meaning when $r/2$ is not an integer, unless you extend $n!$ by the Gamma function as I suggested.

Comment: This post comes from my previous topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427996/erd%c5%91s-theorem-on-2-colorable-sets

Comment: We can define $\binom{x}{k}$ as $\frac{(x-k+1)\dots x}{k!}$, right?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about this definition. When $k$ is odd, my proof does not work, but it does show that for $k$ even you can't hope to have your inequality anyway.

Comment: Can we talk in the chat please? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135620/discussion-between-playgame-and-rondoudou).

Comment: Can you join a chat please?

Comment: @Rondoudou, you do not need to worry about whether $r$ is even or odd. Why? Because $r$ is always even since $r=\left\lfloor \dfrac{k^2}{2}\right\rfloor$. 

Indeed, 
1) if $k=2m$, then $r=\left\lfloor \dfrac{k^2}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \dfrac{4m^2}{2}\right\rfloor=2m^2 \Rightarrow 2\mid r$. 

2) if $k=2m+1$, then $r=\left\lfloor \dfrac{k^2}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \dfrac{4m^2+4m+1}{2}\right\rfloor=2m^2+2m+\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=2m^2+2m \Rightarrow 2\mid r$.

Comment: @Rondoudou, please let me know does it resolve your issue?

Comment: @ZFR Indeed ! Well it just means the asymptotic written above in my solution remains correct in any case. PlayGame in the post you mentioned, the proof quoted gives the same asymptotic as I do, so I'm not sure to understand where the problem remains.

Comment: @Rondoudou You showed that $b \sim \frac{{e\ln 2}}{4}k^2 2^k  \approx 0.47k^2 2^k $, but you add that the OP's inequlaity $b \leq k^2 2^k$ is wrong. Why? Isn't $0.47<1$?

Comment: My bad, I did it in the wrong sense. Thanks for pointing it out, I will correct.

Comment: Now, I think that I finally understood your proof. If we replace $b$ by $[\frac{r\ln 2}{p}]+1$ which is the smallest integer exceeding, the proof will remain valid. So eventually we have shown that $b=[\frac{r\ln 2}{p}]+1\leq k^22^k$ for large $k$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, since $b$ has the same asymptotic behaviour as the smallest integer exceeding. Glad it helped, and sorry for the mistakes !

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135782/discussion-on-answer-by-rondoudou-inequality-for-complicated-expression).

Answer (score 1):

$$r_k=\left\lfloor\dfrac{k^2}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor +\frac{1}{2} (k-1) k$$
$$r_{2k}=2k^2-4k+2 \qquad \text{and}\qquad r_{2k+1}=2k^2-2k$$
$$p_{2k}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } 2^{1-2 (k-1)^2} \Gamma \left(2 k^2-5 k+3\right)}{\Gamma
   \left((k-2) k+\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(k^2-3 k+2\right)}$$
$$p_{2k+1}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } 2^{1-2 (k-1) k} \Gamma \left(2 k^2-3 k+1\right)}{\Gamma
   \left((k-1)^2\right) \Gamma \left((k-1) k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

Now, using Stirling approximation

$$\log\Bigg[\frac{r_{2k}}{p_{2k}}\Bigg]=k \log (2)+\left(2 \log (k)+\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{13}{8 k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$
$$\log\Bigg[\frac{r_{2k+1}}{p_{2k+1}}\Bigg]=k \log (2)+\left(2 \log (k)+\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{7}{8 k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$ So,  if $k$ is even, the equality occurs for
$$k=\frac{13}{2 (1+4 \log (\log (2)))} <0$$ and for odd values of $k$
$$k=\frac{7}{2 (1+4 \log (\log (2)))} <0$$ So the inequality is always true.